# Access 2007: How can I get the onclick event of a Treeview checkbox?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 form that is using an ActiveX Treeview control with checkboxes enabled. I want to run some custom code after a checkbox has been clicked but I can't seem to find any sort of "onclick" or "onchecked" event.

Does anyone know how to do this in Access 2007?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple but definitely not well documented.

Manually add the NodeCheck event to your module.  The key here is that the Properties window won't help you.  You need to enter the code by hand.

```
Private Sub tv1_NodeCheck(ByVal Node As Object)
    'VBA goes here
End Sub
```